# What is the probability that the ball which was taken from the first box and dropped to the second was red?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

The question is:

> There are two boxes denoted as Box-1 & Box-2. In Box-1 there are 5 red
>   and 4 white balls and in Box-2 there are 3 red and 4 white balls.
>   Then, two balls of same colored have been placed placed into Box-2
>   from Box-1. Later, a ball was taken from Box-2 and it was seen that
>   the ball is red. What is the probability that the red ball was in
>   Box-1 initially?

I tried to solve it using bayes theorem. But I couldn't settle it correctly. Need some help. Thanks

Comment: __Hint:__ You have three cases for transfer of balls. Apply Bayes' theorem for each. Also, it would be nice to see your attempt!

Comment: Please choose a more specific title. All questions on this site are about math. Also, tags  like [tag:probability] cover an entire subject; the title is not meant to duplicate the tags but rather to summarize the question more specifically. Finally, note that I removed the [tag:probability-theory] tag; please avail yourself of the tag summaries when choosing tags.

Comment: @joriki, apology. I am new in this community. Next everything will be more specific. Thank you.

Comment: There's an edit button under the question; you can make it more specific this time.

Comment: @Rahul Verma, thanks for the hint. I found two cases, (1) two red balls, (2) two white balls. Then I write, $P(R_1|2R_1)$ = probability of getting $R_1$ when $2R_1$ are added to box-2. In this way, I also proceeded and wrote, $P(R_1|2W_1), P(R_2|2W_1), P(R_2|2R_1)$. Am I doing right?

Comment: ^Here $x_i$= the 'color of $x$' ball from 'box-$i$' where $x=R, W$ and $i=1,2$

Comment: I think your Bayes' expr (for $2W$ case) should look like: $$ P(B_1|R) = \frac{P(B_1)\cdot P(R|B_1)}{P(B_1)\cdot P(R|B_1) + P(B_2)\cdot P(R|B_2)} $$ Similarly, you can write for $2R$ case. And, you're right, there are two cases only (as same colored balls are being transferred).